# One messenger bot on many pages

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

Currently I can use messenger bot on my pages only, but is it possible to create such a bot which can be installed on other's pages? 
At this moment I only see my pages on app subscription page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your application on many pages. 
You need to subscribe your app to another Page via `POST me/subscribed_apps`. (with Page access token)

After subscribing, your application will receive messages sent to other Page and you'll be able to send back message.

Check out fb documentation about [Webhook subscription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/).